# Url Rewrite Regex

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am having trouble with a pesky URL rewrite, the URL `~/global/products/en/page?sdfsdf=sgdfg` works perfectly without the query string but wont work with it. Can anybody help? The mobile site `~/global/products/en/m/page` uses the same rules which is why there is the `[a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*?` in the middle. Rule 6 is my attempt to fix it but I am awful at regex in general so any help would be most appreciated.

```
<add name="rule1" 
     virtualUrl="^~/[a-z-]*/([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*?[^\.])$" 
     rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"   
     destinationUrl="~/country/$1.aspx" 
     ignoreCase="true" />
<add name="rule2" 
     virtualUrl="^~/[a-z-]*/([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*?)(.+)\?(.*)$" 
     rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"    
     destinationUrl="~/country/$1.aspx?$2" 
     ignoreCase="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `ExcludeFromClientQueryString` to `IncludeQueryStringForRewrite`

Like so:-

```
<add name="rule1" 
     virtualUrl="^~/[a-z-]*/([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*?[^\.])$"           
     rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite" 
     destinationUrl="~/country/$1.aspx"  
     ignoreCase="true" />
<add name="rule2" 
     virtualUrl="^~/[a-z-]*/([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*?)(.+)\?(.*)$" 
     rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite" 
     destinationUrl="~/country/$1.aspx?$2" 
     ignoreCase="true"/>
```